# dropdown list with submit in yii

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii

i want to have a drop down list and a submit button, when the button pressed i want to get the text of selected item and store it into db. my drop down code in view is :

```
<?php
                                $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
                                'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true
                                ),
                                )); ?>


                                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'actTopic'); ?>
                                <?php echo $form->error($model,'actTopic'); ?>
                                <?php
                                echo CHtml::dropDownList('actTopic', $category,$list,
                                array('empty' => '... '));
                                ?>
```

it generates a drop down list fine.
but i don't know how i can get the selected item in my action function.
the action function is:

```
public function actiongivePoint()
{       
    $model=new GivePointForm;


    if(isset($_POST['GivePointForm'])){

        $model->attributes=$_POST['GivePointForm'];
        if($model->validate()){
            $actTopic=($model->actTopic);
            $actPoint=($model->actPoint);
            $actId=($model->actId);
            $stCode = (int) $_GET['stCode'];
            $connection=Yii::app()->db;
            $connection->active=TRUE;

            $actIdReader =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select ('actID')
            ->from('refrencepoint')
            ->where("actTopic=:actTopic")
            ->queryScalar(array(':actTopic'=>$actTopic));

            $search =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select ('count(*)')
            ->from('point')
            ->where(array('and', 'actId=:actID', 'stCode=:stCode')  )
            ->queryScalar(array(':actId'=>$actId,':stCode'=>$stCode));          
            if($search !=0){
                $month=CDateFormatter::formatMonth(now());
                $year=CDateFormatter::formatMonth(now());
                $command =$command->update('point', array(
                'year'=>$year,'month'=>$month,
                'pcounter'=>new CDbExpression('pcounter + 1'),),
                (array('and','actId'=>$actId, 'stCode'=>$stCode))) ;

                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('point','....');         
                }   
            else{
                $month=CDateFormatter::formatMonth(now());
                $year=CDateFormatter::formatMonth(now());

                $command->insert('point', array('actId'=>$actId,
                'stCode'=>$stCode,'year'=>$year,'month'=>$month,
                'pcounter'=>new CDbExpression('pcounter + 1')));

                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('point','....');         
    }

}
}                           
    $this->render('givePoint',array('model'=>$model));

}
```

i should  say i don't use active record.

with above codes it looks like everything is ok in view, but when i press submit button nothing happen, no change in db and even no error just the page refresh!!

what is wrong here?
i am so tired of trying....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just use like it.

you first use foreach loop.I am not sure which type of things your are listing. but you need to do work like in below.

**It is an example**

```
foreach($model->category as $list) {
   $list['id'] = $list->name;
}
echo CHtml::dropDownList($model, 'actTopic', $list);
```

Now you debug your code.

```
public function actiongivePoint()
{       
$model=new GivePointForm;
if(isset($_POST['GivePointForm'])){

print_r($_POST['GivePointForm']);
exit; //Just check either the form is posted or not and values are coming or not.

$model->attributes=$_POST['GivePointForm'];
if($model->validate()){
$actTopic=($model->actTopic);

echo $actTopic ;
exit ;                 // Check either your dropdown item id is coming or not.
```

Hope its help you.

Thanks.